# Count records is always 1

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm trying to get a count of the records that exist in the DB  with a certain name and I am trying to use this code:

```
            query = client.Cypher
                .Match("(n { Name: 'a'})")
                .Return(n => n.Count())
                .Results.Count();
```

It's looking for a user with a name of 'a'.  The problem I have is that if the database has no records or if there is a record with the name of 'a', I always get 1 as the result of the code.  I would expect to have 0 when there are no records in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the last `Count()` is returning the number of elements returned by `.Return(n => n.Count()`, which will always be 1 element (a single number).

Try removing `.Count()` from the end (and replacing it with `Single()`):

```
query = client.Cypher
              .Match("(n { Name: 'a'})")
              .Return(n => n.Count())
              .Results
              .Single();
```

Comment: That code results in:  Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<long>' to 'long

I declare my query variable and set a value to detect a change, it is declared as: long query = 987;

Comment: I've also tried ToString anywhere it would let me.  That resulted in different errors

Comment: I think .Single() is going to be it, I've been testing and it looks good.  Thx